# Como arreglo este codigo, es algo sencillo pero no puedo corregirlo

Tags: java

Necesito que la variable "Nombre" se obtenga del jTextField1 para luego mostrar un mensaje que muestra la palabra bienvenido y la informacion de la variable

```
 String Nombre;

this.jTextField1.getText();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bievenido "+Nombre"");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitas que se guarde en la variable Nombre puede quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
 String Nombre= jTextField1.getText();
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido "+Nombre);
```

Pero si tu objetivo es solo mostrar el contenido de jTextField1, puedes usar lo siguiente y te ahorras la variable Nombre.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido "+jTextField1.getText());
```

Tu error es porque no estas armando bien la cadena a mostrar. Quita las comillas que tienes al final.

```
"Bienvenido "+Nombre
```

Comment: Gracias, eso lo soluciono todo

Comment: De nada. Para eso estamos.